Perform operation on a flux element based on previous element result
I have three classes of type Work like below.
interface Work{
        boolean execute();
    }

    class Service1 implements Work{

        @Override
        boolean execute(){
            //some complex logic
            return true;
        }
    }

    class Service2 implements Work{

        @Override
        boolean execute(){
            //some complex logic
            return true;
        }
    }

    class Service3 implements Work{

        @Override
        boolean execute(){
            //some complex logic
            return true;
        }
    }

I want to stream each of these from a list as flux and execute the next service only if the current element's execute method returns true.
Service1 service1 = new Service1();
Service2 service2 = new Service2();
Service3 service3 = new Service3();
List<Work> serviceList = List.of(service1, service2, service3);
Flux<Work> services = Flux.fromStream(serviceList.stream());

//?? how to process the next element based on current element's result

I could do this with the Mono by chaining through flatMap like below, but I wanted to achieve this using Flux.
Mono<Work> service1Mono = Mono.just(service1);
Mono<Work> service2Mono = Mono.just(service2);
Mono<Work> service3Mono = Mono.just(service3);
Mono<Work> workResult = service1Mono.flatMap(a->{
  if(a.execute())
       return service2Mono;
  return Mono.just(a);
}).flatMap(b -> {
  if(b.execute())
        return service3Mono;
  return Mono.just(b);
});
//do something with the workResult

UPDATE:
Providing more info specific to my use case. I am trying to implement a simple saga orchestrator pattern. So lets say I have three classes
public interface Work {

    Mono<WorkResult> execute();

    Mono<WorkResult> compensate();
}

public class SomeWork implements Work{
    @Override
    public Mono<WorkResult> execute() {
        WorkResult result = new WorkResult();
        result.setName("SomeWork");
        result.setValid(true);
        return Mono.just(result);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<WorkResult> compensate() {
        return null;
    }
}

public class SomeOtherWork implements Work{
    @Override
    public Mono<WorkResult> execute() {
        WorkResult result = new WorkResult();
        result.setName("SomeOtherWork");
        result.setValid(true);
        return Mono.just(result);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<WorkResult> compensate() {
        return null;
    }
}

public class SomeMoreWork  implements Work{
    @Override
    public Mono<WorkResult> execute() {
        WorkResult result = new WorkResult();
        result.setName("SomeMoreWork");
        result.setValid(false);
        return Mono.just(result);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<WorkResult> compensate() {
        return null;
    }
}

My work result is:
public class WorkResult {

    private Boolean isValid;
    private String name;

    public Boolean getValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    public void setValid(Boolean valid) {
        isValid = valid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

And here is my orchestrator:
public class OrchestratorEngine {

    public void start(List<Work> workList){

        System.out.println("In orchestrator engine..");
        WorkResult workResult = new WorkResult();
        workResult.setValid(true);
        workResult.setName("DummyWork");
        Mono<WorkResult> response = Mono.just(workResult);

        //this set has name of failed service
        Set<String> failedService = new HashSet<>();
        //this map has indexes of services from the workList
        Map<String, Integer> workMap = new HashMap<>();
        workMap.put("SomeWork",0);workMap.put("SomeOtherWork",1);workMap.put("SomeMoreWork",2);

        for(Work work: workList){
            response = response.flatMap(result -> {
                if(result.getValid()) {
                    System.out.println(result.getName());
                    failedService.add(result.getName());
                    return work.execute();
                }
                return Mono.just(result);
            });
        }

        response = response.flatMap(result->{
            if(result.getValid()){
                System.out.println(result.getName());
                failedService.add(result.getName());
            }
            return Mono.just(result);
        });

        response.subscribe(result->{
            //compensating events start
            if(!failedService.isEmpty()) {
                //get the failed service index
                int index = workMap.get(failedService.iterator().next());
                //call compensate on previous services
                for(int i=index; i>=0; i--){
                    workList.get(i).compensate().subscribe();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}


What do you want as a result ? A flux that send all services that have been executed ? Or do you want each to be returned by the flux, even if they do not have been executed ?

Hi, I want each mono in the list to execute and whenever the result is available, based on a condition on that result, call the next mono.

@inderd why do you want to use Reactor for that? execute returns a boolean, and there is nothing else that reacts to something

hm, the updated code looks interesting. but can you tell how you want to use the compensate? I'm not quite understand the relation

I modified the OrchestratorEngine to show how compensate would be called.

I think I found a way how to achieve this. I hope this is not blocking in any way. Here is the code.
Service1 service1 = new Service1();
    Service2 service2 = new Service2();
    Service3 service3 = new Service3();

    Work initialWork = new Work() {
        @Override
        public boolean execute() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    Mono<Work> response = Mono.just(initialWork);

    Mono<Work> service1Mono = Mono.just(service1);
    Mono<Work> service2Mono = Mono.just(service2);
    Mono<Work> service3Mono = Mono.just(service3);

    List<Mono<Work>> workList = List.of(service1Mono, service2Mono, service3Mono);
    for(Mono<Work> work: workList){
        response = response.flatMap(result -> {
            if(result.execute())
                return work;
            return Mono.just(result);
        });
    }

    //process the final service3Mono
    response = response.flatMap(result -> {
        System.out.println(result.execute());
        return Mono.just(result);
    });

    response.subscribe();

Initially, I created some dummy work that will default to true. With this result, I would iterate on each of those Monos from the list, do a flatMap and then return the next Mono only if the current Mono returns true. In the end, I'll trigger the last Mono in case it reaches that point. Then, subscribe to the whole response.

Are you sure this is a reactive code? I mean, I understand that it's a simplification of an approach you use in real code, but if it's really close to that example it doesn't seem you're getting any benefits of the reactor

Honestly, I am new to the reactive programming. Do you think the above code is blocking anywhere? I think I was just chaining each of the Monos of the same type in an iterative way. Nothing will happen until the response is subscribed. I could still return the response Mono, if any client called this code.

I mean, it looks imperative to me. Ex. those just, and the fact it has a loop. But I'm not sure about the other parts and the exact goal

As you said, this is just a simplified version. In the actual implementation, the execute method actially returns a Mono and the Services are just beans of same type. In any case, keeping the style aside, would you think any part of the code is blocking?

I think if you provide more details about what you have it would be much more clear what could be a solution. Because in the code you're having non-reactive methods, and it's very hard to understand how it's translated to a real reactive code.

@IgorArtamonov I have provided more details in the original post specific to my use case.

My understanding is that you want to execute the services one by one until the first of them returns valid=true. And run compensate for those that returned false.
In this case it could be something like:
List<Work> works = ...;

Mono<String> executed = Flux.fromIterable(works)
   .flatMap(work -> {
       return work.execute().flatMap(result -> {
          if (result.isValid()) {
             return Mono.just(work.getName());
          } else {
             return work.compensate().then(Mono.empty());
          }
       })
  }, 1) // 1 work at a time
  .next();

executed.subscribe();


Actually no, the whole transaction is not said to be complete unless every work is done in the list. Once a work fails, rest of the works should not be executed. So the compensate would kick off backwards, from the failed work, essentially rolling back the whole transaction.
